# Workaround needed: webdriver/maven tests should run on each deploy in jenkins, but

Tags: maven, jenkins, webdriver, xvfb

We have some webdriver/testng/maven/java tests that we need to run automatically after each deploy, but its been 4 days and I just cant get the damn thing to work headlessly using xvfb.
And I do not have access to the server, and to Jenkins configuration, other to constantly bugging the poor guy who operates these.

So what kind of a workaround would you offer in this case?
Can Jenkins do jobs on remote servers (say I find a server that doesnt need to run tests headlessly)?
Or is there an alternative to xvfb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your selenium tests to use remote webdriver

For info read here - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver
and http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-s-drivers

**UPDATE**

Jeeny - "Can Jenkins do jobs on remote servers (say I find a server that doesnt need to run tests headlessly)?"

Amey - "Yes"

BUT instead of running the Jenkins job on a remote server, make your selenium tests run on a remote server.

I assume you initialize your selenium webdriver browser instance by this command

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

change that to

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://your.remote.server:4444/wd/hub", webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

Comment: You can deploy jenkins locally on a system and you can execute test cases at a specific time of the day probably late night after the final build of the day. This would allow you to execute test cases in non headless manner as well.

Comment: @amey - can you please put this in some context. how can I relate this to the situation?

Comment: @Vinay - so I set up a computer that will remain turned on, when I leave work and I install Jenkins on it, connect it to the project and do a job that will start a normal Firefox which will run the tests some time at night?

Comment: Yup it will. That is how I run my jobs

Comment: Actually I can't use this approach, because we need to run the tests on the new code, and if they fail, not do the deploy, which is done on another machine.

Comment: Hmmm then if it is a maven project you can merge your pom code with developers code. By default if the build fails then your code will not get executed. Cheers.. Hope this helped...